# Facing Problem about Image overflow in Grid Layout

Tags: html, css, image, grid

```
/* mobile approach header*/
.container {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(9, auto);
  }
  img {
    width: 100vw;
  }
} /* Tablet approach*/
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* header*/
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: right;
    height: auto;
  } /*gallery*/
  .tablet-main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(5, 100vh) / 50fr 50fr;
    grid-template-areas: "image1 image2" "image3 image4" "image5 image6" "image7 image8" "image9 .";
  }
  .pic {
    display: none;
  }
  .bread {
    grid-area: image1;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .candies {
    grid-area: image2;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .charries {
    grid-area: image3;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .eclair {
    grid-area: image4;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .fruit {
    grid-area: image5;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .milk {
    grid-area: image6;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .orange {
    grid-area: image7;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other information? what problem you are experiencing and what do you wish to achieve ?

Comment: my images are not adjusting in the grid. size of grid automatically increasing with images.  and images are also overflowing through grid.

Comment: @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* header*/
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: right;
    height: auto;
  } /*gallery*/
  .tablet-main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(5, 100vh) / 50fr 50fr;
    grid-template-areas: "image1 image2" "image3 image4";
  }
  .pic {
    display: none;
  }
  .bread {
    grid-area: image1;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .candies {
    grid-area: image2;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }